# Want to redirect my site from www to non.www https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect my site from HTTP with www to HTTPS non-www I used the following code but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: You just need to add `OR` in 2nd condition to make it `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]`

Answer (score 1):

You were on right path following modifications to your rule may help you. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

These Rules will redirect from either www or without it to https.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond https !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```